# How to choose indexes for chat application database

Tags: sql-server, database-design, indexing, chat

I work on a small chat application with database. I create the database shown in the image.
[image: Database for chat application]

I new to indexes and I want to choose the appropriate indexes for the query.

Can I use clustered index in the Messages table ? and if I can, Which column (or columns) should have clustered index ? or should I use non-clustered index ?

**Update**: The query that I user to get messages is :

```
 Select TextContent From Messages where (SenderId='1' and ReciverID = '2') or (SenderId='2' and ReciverID = '1') order by date
```

The values for SenderID and ReciverID is just for clarification.

Comment: You don't create indexes for the database, you create indexes for the queries. It's impossible to advice the indexes before we see the queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should add a surrogate primary key to your messages table and create an index:

```
ALTER TABLE messages ADD COLUMN id BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY

ALTER TABLE messages ADD CONSTRAINT pk_messages_id PRIMARY KEY (id)

CREATE INDEX ix_messages_sender_receiver_date (senderId, receiverId, date) ON messages
```

If you want to retrieve, say, just top 10 last messages from the conversation chain, it might help to rewrite your query a little:

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  TOP 10
                *
        FROM    (
                SELECT  date, id
                FROM    messages
                WHERE   senderId = 1 AND receiverId = 2
                UNION
                SELECT  date, id
                FROM    messages
                WHERE   senderId = 2 AND receiverId = 1
                ) q
        ORDER BY
                date DESC, id DESC
        ) q
JOIN    messages m
ON      m.id = q.id
```

This way, SQL Server is more likely to merge join the two directions of the conversation rather than sorting them separately.

Alternatively, instead of sender and receiver, use `user1`, `user2` and `direction`, so that `user1 < user2` (always) and `direction` defines whether the text goes from `user1` to `user2` or vise versa.

This way, you can always filter simply on `user1 = 1 AND user2 = 2`, without having to worry about `OR` or unions.

You can do that in computed columns which you can also index:

```
ALTER TABLE messages ADD COLUMN user1 AS CASE WHEN senderId < receiverId THEN senderId ELSE receiverId END

ALTER TABLE messages ADD COLUMN user2 AS CASE WHEN senderId > receiverId THEN senderId ELSE receiverId END

ALTER TABLE messages ADD COLUMN direction AS CASE WHEN senderId < receiverId THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

CREATE INDEX ix_messages_user1_user2_date ON messages (user1, user2, date)
```

then select:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    messages
WHERE   user1 = 1
        AND user2 = 2 -- make sure lower number goes to user1, higher number goes to user2
ORDER BY
        date
```

Comment: Very good answer. But the way you create index in not correct. Index is created as follow : CREATE INDEX index_Name on [dbo].[Message] ([SenderId],[ReseverId] ,[MessageDate] )

Comment: Last thing, why I should add surrogate primary key ?

Comment: @AhmedShamel: so that you, for instance, can differentiate between messages posted with the same timestamp.

Comment: If it is only for differentiate between messages posted with the same timestamp why it must be a primary key ?
Primary key will create clustered index. Does creating clustered index has any advantage here ?

Comment: @AhmedShamel: can't tell before I see your other queries. But if you are going to reference your messages by pk from other tables (say link a message url with id), this would come handy too.

Comment: The index in the answer is non-clustered. Can I make clustered index for user1, user2, and ID (instead of date) ? 

In other words, the three columns (user1,user2 and ID) will be a primary key.

Comment: @AhmedShamel: primary key and clustering are different things. You should cluster by the column(s) you do the lookup on most often.

Comment: I sorry for that. As I say in the question, I new to indexes. Can the primary be the three columns (user1, user2 and ID)

Comment: @Quassnoi why do you need date for your index? aren't sender and receiver enough?

Comment: @DignityDignity: because the query is ordering by date