# Optimizing chat application database

Tags: sql-server, indexing, chat, primary-key

I work on a simple chat application with database. The database for the project is shown in the image.

The direction column in the message table is just to determine if user1 is the sender or user2 is the sender.

[image: Database for chat application]

I use this query to get the messages :

```
SELECT  TextContent,Direction FROM Messages
WHERE   User1 = 1 AND User2 = 2 
ORDER BY Date
```

The values for User1 and User2 is just for clarification.

I have two questions :

1. I didn't choose a primary key for Messages table. Should I simply choose the ID column as a primary key or select multiple columns for the primary key ?
2. Should I create an index on (User1,User2,
   Date) columns or on (User1,User2,ID) columns ?. Should I create a cluster index or non-cluster index ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to choose indexes for chat application database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149569/how-to-choose-indexes-for-chat-application-database)

Comment: @mohan111 This is not duplicate. The question here is more specific. I tried to get the complete answer from the question  in the link, but I can't. The programer that answer the question didn't answer for my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should define a primary key clustered index on the ID column.

Yes, you should define a nonclustered composite index on (User1, User2, Date). ID is already "included" in the nonclustered index if you define ID as the clustered index.

Comment: Good answer, but why ID should be primary key ?

Comment: It's complex and I could write a book on the topic. To answer your question simply... Having primary key as ID, which I'm assuming you also set as an identity, will ensure that you don't accidentally assign 2 rows with the same ID. Defining it as the clustered index will ensure that new rows are added to the end of the last page, preventing page splits. (page splits are a long topic that most people naively don't know about)...

Comment: Also, using a single integer column (4 bytes) as the clustered index instead of a composite of multiple columns will make all nonclustered indexes on the table smaller and more compact since the value of the clustered index gets added behind the scenes to all nonclustered index rows.